# How to update the query reference of a firebase recycler adapter when button is clicked?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a RecyclerView bound to a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. I need to update the data displayed based on a value set by the user using Edittext and called function using button. data is only updated when i resume activity from recents.

Something like this:

```
   public void refreshadappter(String url)
{
           adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Home,HomeViewHolder>(
            Home.class,
            R.layout.home_card,
            HomeViewHolder.class,
             mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(url)
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(HomeViewHolder viewHolder, 
       Home model, final int position) {
            viewHolder.name.setText(model.getName());
            viewHolder.religion.setText(model.getReligion());
        }
    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`?